# Maven Plugin for Azure Web Apps "<appServicePlanName>" not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, maven-plugin

Created new project using latest Maven Azure Functions Archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.11
```

I am using following tag in pom file.

```
<appServicePlanName>XXX2Plan</appServicePlanName>
```

**Doc says :** Specifies the name of the existing App Service Plan when you do not want to create a new one.

but after deployment its creating new APP SERVICE PLAN insted of using existing one, i am wonder if anyone solved it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaquar-khan-demo-azure-java-function</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.0.0-beta-2</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.0.0-beta-4</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>vaquar-azure-java-function-demo</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>canadaeast</functionAppRegion>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <functionResourceGroup>XXXXXX</functionResourceGroup>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <appServicePlanName>XXX2Plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>beta</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>host.json</include>
                                        <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/maven/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/readme

> Workaround: First manually create function and then deploy using maven
>   insted of allow maven to create function for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document you mentioned is for azure web app, while [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/tree/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin#configurations) for functions says only following properties are supported, including `resourceGroup/appName/region/pricingTier/appSettings/deploymentType`.

And we can see there's no code implementation  about `appServicePlanName` in [function plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/blob/develop/azure-functions-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/maven/function/AbstractFunctionMojo.java), while it is implemented in [web app plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/blob/master/azure-webapp-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/maven/webapp/AbstractWebAppMojo.java#L68).

So I assume for now it's not supported to deploy function app to existing app service plan using maven plugin.

And workaround is to create new function app on portal first, then deploy functions to this app with mvn plugin.

**Update**

Not supported indeed, see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/183).

**Update2**

This feature has been supported from `1.0.0-beta-3` azure-functions-maven-plugin.

Need to Add `<appServicePlanName>existingplanname</appServicePlanName>` under `<properties>`.