# Can Azure Functions and webapp share same APP SERVICE PLAN

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have three azure function and two webapp, i want all app in same APP SERVICE PLAN but azure manual and maven both not allowed to add same APP SERVICE PLAN.

[image]

Is it possible in azure to add web and function app in same APP SERVICE PLAN ?

Comment: You posted [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893680/maven-plugin-for-azure-web-apps-appserviceplanname-not-working) shortly before this current one, and they are both about the same thing. Please don't post duplicate questions, if you don't get an immediate response. You can edit your original question to include the graphic above

Comment: You mean to say if going with fix plan insted of consumption plan maven plugin will work ? ,I feel issue with maven plugin issue as all other tag values refracted except service plan .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can, as long as it's a fixed App Service Plan (not Consumption Plan). You can do that via Azure portal, not sure about maven.

Comment: I can share a consumption plan if I create the plan and functions with Pulumi. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @JonCanning For Consumption Plan it doesn't really matter. You can have 1 plan for many apps or 1-per-1, there is no effect on scalability or pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to setup a web app and a function app that share an app service Plan (Tier: Standard, B1) with [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/) and always received following error when the web app should get created:
`web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>`

When using separate service plans for web apps and function apps, it works fine.