# Azure function app billing per app when using a shared plan

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

Lets say I create three different function apps on a single app service plan, is it possible to get usage per function app? I am building a multi tenant system and I am planning to create one function app per tenant but all of these share the same app service plan. I would like to bill the customers based on their usage. So, is it possible to get the usage metrics or bill broken down at the function app level even if they all share the same app service plan underneath?

What is the suggested way for deploying multi tenant applications? I can create one app service plan per function app/tenant, but as the number of tenants grow, it would be too many plans and if I need pre-warmed instances, it would turn out too expensive. Most tenants are idle and it makes sense to share computing resources across tenants in my case.

Can you please share relevant documentation on Azure that supports the answer?

Answer (score -2):

You will only pay for the shared App Service Plan that can be shared as mentioned over [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894222/can-azure-functions-and-webapp-share-same-app-service-plan#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20they%20can%2C%20as%20long%20as%20it%27s%20a,that%20via%20Azure%20portal%2C%20not%20sure%20about%20maven.).

For more information on App service Plan costs, take a in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-manage-costs) on "Plan and manage costs for Azure App Service".

Comment: The answer is not clear, doesn't talk about whether I can get the cost per function app or not. I understand what I pay from the pricing page, but the question is more about getting a breakup at the function app level.

Comment: That's not an option. You will get billed by the App Service Plan. There's no breakdown possible of what App/Function that's running on top of it.